# How to ensure all directories exist before to fs.writeFile using node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm wondering what is the proper way to ensure that all folder in a path exist before to write a new file.

In the following example, the code fails because the folder `cache` doesn't exists.

```
    fs.writeFile(__config.path.base + '.tmp/cache/shared.cache', new Date().getTime(), function(err) {
        if (err){
            consoleDev('Unable to write the new cache timestamp in ' + __filename + ' at ' + __line, 'error');
        }else{
            consoleDev('Cache process done!');
        }

        callback ? callback() : '';
    });
```

**Solution:**

```
    // Ensure the path exists with mkdirp, if it doesn't, create all missing folders.
    mkdirp(path.resolve(__config.path.base, path.dirname(__config.cache.lastCacheTimestampFile)), function(err){
        if (err){
            consoleDev('Unable to create the directories "' + __config.path.base + '" in' + __filename + ' at ' + __line + '\n' + err.message, 'error');
        }else{
            fs.writeFile(__config.path.base + filename, new Date().getTime(), function(err) {
                if (err){
                    consoleDev('Unable to write the new cache timestamp in ' + __filename + ' at ' + __line + '\n' + err.message, 'error');
                }else{
                    consoleDev('Cache process done!');
                }

                callback ? callback() : '';
            });
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since node 10 you can create the entire path with a single command by setting `options.recursive` to true:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(folder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(folder, { recursive: true });
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsmkdirsyncpath-options

Answer (score 5):

[fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra#ensurefilefile-callback) has a function I found useful for doing this.

The code would be something like:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

fs.ensureFile(path, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    fs.writeFile(path, ...);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/mkdir).

If you really want to do it yourself (recursively):

```
var pathToFile = 'the/file/sits/in/this/dir/myfile.txt';

pathToFile.split('/').slice(0,-1).reduce(function(prev, curr, i) {
  if(fs.existsSync(prev) === false) { 
    fs.mkdirSync(prev); 
  }
  return prev + '/' + curr;
});
```

You need the slice to omit the file itself.

Comment: You should remove slice. It skips the last folder since you're working on the previous value. It will never reach the file even without slice since it's the last current, and will never be prev.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fs.existsSync to check if your dir exists and create it if not :

```
if (fs.existsSync(pathToFolder)===false) {
    fs.mkdirSync(pathToFolder,0777);
}
```

Comment: Will this create all levels of the path that don't exist?  Also, why introduce synchronous code into an asynchronous operation?

Comment: synchronous prevents your writefile to run before the folder creation. @hobbs mkdirp is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for answers, sync or async won't be an issue indeed. I'll try ASAP and accept the answer if it does work ;)